# python scatter ndarray dimension size error and rgb color issue

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter

I am having trouble making a scatter plot with a log scale for the values. The arrays I have are numpy ndarray's. x.size = 19, y.size = 18, and data is 19x18. It is telling me "ValueError: x and y must be the same size". But they shouldn't have to be?! I tried botching it and just making each one 18, but then it wasn't converting my data values to the 0-1 range and it was giving me an rbg color error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
from matplotlib.colors import (LogNorm, Normalize,SymLogNorm)
from matplotlib.ticker import (LogLocator, LogFormatter, LogFormatterMathtext, 
                           MultipleLocator)
x= np.arange(19)
y = np.arange(18)
data = np.random.random_sample((19, 18))

sc =ax2.scatter(x,y,c=data,norm=LogNorm(),
                cmap=get_cmap('Spectral_r'),edgecolors='none')
cbar1 = fig.colorbar(sc,ax=ax2,ticks=LogLocator(),format=LogFormatterMathtext())
```

Comment: Please can you make a complete example? There seems to be a) a lot of irrelevant code that is included and b) a lot of relevant code that is missing. This makes it harder to answer the question properly. Make it so we can directly run your code to reproduce the error. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Alight hopefully that is better

Comment: I meant something more like this: http://pastebin.com/kJMgPNt6 . See what I mean?

Comment: Yeah, I see. What I have now should run on anyones machine.

Comment: Could you show a picture of what you want your plot to look like?  I ask because your data doesn't obviously fit the usual "scatterplot" structure.  If you don't have one available, check out the matplotlib gallery: http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x`, `y` and `c` must all be the same size as they are mapped by position (`zip(x, y, c)` should return the position and color tuples you want).

Try something like

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)   # makes 2D X, Y arrays for every grid point

sc = plt.scatter(X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), c=c.ravel(), ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot

> The data is displayed as a collection of
>   points, each having the value of one variable determining the position
>   on the horizontal axis and the value of the other variable determining
>   the position on the vertical axis.

You are not plotting two separate arrays when you make a scatter plot. You are plotting `N` two-dimensional points. In the the function you are using, you supply the x and y coordinates separately. This is why they must be the same length.

Maybe a scatter plot is not what you are after in this case?

Comment: Yeah I got the scatter plot to work, but maybe a pcolor type plot would look better here..